# Negative with AS LONG AS

Tags: grammar

Do we use 'as long as' in a negative sentence?

> Such as: As long as a man doesn’t show humility, he can’t keep his
> relations going.

Is this ok?

Or does it have to be like this:

> Until a man shows humility, he can’t keep his relations going.

Comment: I have read in an Indian grammar “ She is not as beautiful as her friends” is incorrect. The correct form “ she is not so beautiful as her friends”

Comment: @JayHo if you want a response you should ask a question about it. Otherwise consider deleting your comment, as it does not relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/long), ***as long as*** has three meanings:

> as long as or so long as
>
> 1  : since
>
> ```
> As long as I'm here, we may as well begin.
> As long as you're up, would you mind getting me a drink?
> So long as you feel that way I'll leave.
> ```
>
> 2  : if
>
> ```
> I'll go with you as long as you'll drive.
> They can do anything they want, so long as they follow the rules.
> As long as she's allowed to go first, she's happy.
> ```
>
> 3  : during the time that : while
>
> ```
> The economy will remain strong as long as there are jobs to go around.
> ```

Try these examples:

### Since

*As long as the lake is **not frozen over**, we can go boating.

As long as my teacher has **not left** his office, we can go there and see him now.*

### If

As long as the children **seldom** cry or yell, they can go with us.

The tent will not collapse as long as there **isn't** a high wind.

### While

The economy will **not recover** as long as the pilots remain on strike.

As long as the pilots **do not remain** on strike, the economy will recover soon.

**So, yes, we can use *as long as* in negative sentences.**

Comment: Note Merriam-Webster is US English. I have never heard the first usage outside US sources, and Cambridge Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-long-as-and-so-long-as does not give it.

Comment: @Peter  Thanks!  That is all good to know.